# Difference between cytospin and metaphase spread protocol

Tags: protocol

I would like to know what exactly is the difference between cytospin and metaphase protocol. I'm a data scientist helping a medical lab and I receive images of cells with particular types of DNA. The DNA comes stained with DAPI. However, other times, if the scientists can pinpoint a particular gene in the DNA, they stain it with FISH. I asked the following: When I separate the image into the separate color signals (RGB),  will I see the DNA in both the green gray scale images and the blue gray scale images, I was told that you can but it won't be that clear since cytospin spread protocol has worse quality than metaphase spread protocol.

What exactly is the scientist referring to? I looked at some articles but the methodologies are a bit beyond me and it would be helpful if it can be answered in broader terms.